# Passing argument to function. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/EcCTx/)

am I trying to pass an argument to a function, but it doesn't receive the argument or it isn't executed.

```
<a href="javascript:addRemove('7249');">Details</a>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function addRemove(u) {
    alert(u);
    }

});
```

Any ideas what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` creates a scope out of which functions can't escape (the result is that you can't call them by their name from the global context). Take `addRemove` out of it and it'll work.

Comment: There are better solutions though (like event handlers). Someone's bound to post an answer with a decent amount of detail, so you might as well wait for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/EcCTx/2/

Your code was wrapped in an onload event *by jsfiddle* (drop-down menu on the left). So if you add a function it won't be global, but your onclick event calls a global function by the name `addRemove`.

Answer (score 6):

Your function only exists within the scope of the ready event handler, you need to move function addRemove outside of the ready function.

Comment: @Sandra, http://jsfiddle.net/EcCTx/2/ don't let jsfiddle wrap your javascript in an onload event (the drop-down on the left)

Comment: @davin :  you found the problem. Post it and I will accept it as the answer =)

Answer (score 3):

You need to define your function outside of the `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 2):

the `addRemove` function must be outside of `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested it, but my guess is this: things inside of a function can't be accessed from outside of a function. For example,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function addRemove(u) {
        alert(u);
    }
});
console.log(addRemove); // reference error or something similar
```

You should define `addRemove` function **outside** of `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 1):

You had no defined function called addRemove in the Fiddle!

I've added this, and removed the inline javascript calls.

See this for better way of doing it:

http://jsfiddle.net/EcCTx/6/

Answer (score 1):

In case Davin doesn't come back, here's the answer: jsFiddle defaults to wrapping your JS in the 'onLoad' method - and we can't allow that.

http://jsfiddle.net/nqbWe/

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specifically calling that function. In the document ready part you have the function set up, but the anchor will not call that function by itself. In this instance it will only be called when someone clicks on that link.

You could give the link a class and data attribute and use those with jQuery to have something happen on page load.

Comment: But there doesn't appear an alert when I click on the links.